# How to replace all occurrences in a line from reading a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

With the given code, it replaces and does what it should do, the problem is that it doesn't replace multiple in a same line, only the first one it finds, then moves on to next line.

The data structure looks like this:

```
if js.hasItemById(I06N) and js.hasItemById(I064)
    js.getItemById(I088).remove()
    js.getItemById(I061).remove()
    js.addItemById(I06Y)
```

It replaces everything in the parentheses , but (I064) for example does not get replaced, only the first found occurrence.

```
uniques = []
count = 0
code = ""
new_text = ""
## --- FINDS THE ITEMS IN BRACKETS, TO REPLACE --- ##
with open("nest.txt", "r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        open_br = line.find("(")
        close_br = line.find(")")

        in_brackets = line[open_br + 1:close_br]
        
        if in_brackets in uniques:
            code = "ITEM_" + str(uniques.index(in_brackets))

        else:
            uniques.append(in_brackets)
            code = "ITEM_" + str(count)
            count += 1

        new_text += line.replace(in_brackets, code)
        

    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate(0)
    f.write(new_text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined in the [documentation for str.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=find#str.find), it only finds the first character match in the string provided.

So, the `line.find("(")` function here returns the first/lowest index where the character matches the '(' character. And then we are only storing the first matching word.

One way to find every occurrence of the bracket sequence, is by using the regular expressions library.

```
for line in f:
    re.findall(r'\([a-z0-9A-Z]+\)', line)
```

Otherwise, you could also check each character and store the letters inside the brackets as matches.